# Cells in UICollectionview not removing on deleting image at index

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` in which in have set background images for cells.

```
UIImage *image = imageArray[indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

The problem is that if i delete an image from the array that is used to create the `UICollectionView` and reload the `collectionView`, the cell is removed but the image is still displayed.

Here is my delete and refresh code:

```
[collectionImages performBatchUpdates:^{
    [imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row
                                                 inSection:0];
    [collectionImages deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                               indexPath1]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];

[collectionImages setNeedsDisplay];
```

The main problem is that the image is deleted from the array and even from the `UICollectionView` but is not removed from the view. Seems like it is being displayed somewhere from a cache.

Comment: might cause with the block . Try to reload in the **completion:^(BOOL finished)**

Comment: Tried it and nothing happened!

Comment: Can you clarify where is the first block of code and where is the second? I mean, in which methods are they placed?

Comment: The first block of code is in the (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath function and the second block is in the method that deletes an image from the array.

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine. To test it, I created a project and created a method "deleteImageFromIndex:" that is called on ViewDidAppear. But i set the number of items in section as collectionImages.count. Where exactly are you calling the delete method and how did you set the number of items in section?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The main problem here is that the image is the array and the uicollectionView is actually deleting since i cant click on it after its deleted abd even the array count shows a lesser value. But the image keeps showing in its placeholder and doesn't get removed. It seems like the UiCollection reloads from some cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[collectionImages reloadData];` instead of `[collectionImages setNeedsDisplay];`.

Comment: I have already tried this and it didnt work. Thanks for your input though!